# Adding custom log locations to the OS X console application

Tags: macos, logging, console

After searching online, the best solution I've found so far is to just make a symbolic link in either "/Library/logs/" or "~/Library/logs/" to get it to show up in the Console application.

I'm wondering if it would be possible to add a new directory or log file to the "root" level directly under the "LOG FILES" section in the console.

Here's a quick screenshot:

[image: OS X Console]

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible.

If you're generating log files, you should generate them into one of the standard locations anyway, so this won't be an issue.

Comment: The standard locations according to Apple's Console.app don't include Homebrew's /usr/local/var/log, which I'd call pretty standard for anyone who uses the command line in OS X.

Comment: Homebrew is a third-party add-on, it's not part of the OS. It shouldn't be defining its own log locations, it should be using the standard locations just like everything else.

Comment: All kinds of product use non-standard log locations, most commonly own their own application folders. Try Glassfish for instance.

Comment: That means Console won’t pick them up. They should use a standard location if possible, so they’re picked up by Console.

Answer (score 42):

There is one way to get your log files into the console.

You can add a symlink to the log file or log directory to one of the directories in the list. The directory `~/Library/Logs` seems like the logical choice for adding your own log files.

---

For myself I wanted easy access to apache2 logs. I installed apache2 using [macports](http://www.macports.org/) and the default log file is located at `/opt/local/apache2/logs`.

Thus all I did was create the symlink to that directory.

```
# cd ~/Library/Logs
# ln -s /opt/local/apache2/logs/ apache2
```

Now I can easily use the console.app to get to the logs.

Comment: It looks like Mountain Lion removes this feature. Console doesn't display symlinks at all, any more.

Comment: This worked for me in Mountain Lion. Only problem was that I had to manually grant read access to those files before they were readable in Consoe.app

Comment: Works for me in 10.8.4

Comment: On OSX 10.9 I can't have a symbolic link to a folder, but a folder contains symbolic link for each files works. I use it for MAMP logs

Comment: This worked for Single file but not the folder. It does not show my entire Xampp Log folder

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on macOS 10.12... Tried for both folders and single files (MongoDB log files).

Comment: @NicCottrell My symlink has `r` for all and it does not work in Console.app.

Answer (score 8):

My solution for macOS Sierra:

First and last step, you must create a hard link from your source (log) directory into (as example) one of existing official log directories, you can seen in console.app.

I take my `~/Library/Logs` directory for that.

`hln /usr/local/var/log /Users/dierk/Library/Logs/_usr_local_var_log`

*Cross-posting this [great tool for creating hardlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5118678/195835) originally posted by [Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634331/sam).*

**Short intro:**

To install Hardlink, ensure you've installed homebrew, then run:

`brew install hardlink-osx`

Once installed, create a hard link with:

`hln [source] [destination]`

Comment: Can't try it myself as my logs are on different device and I get "hln: Cross-device link" but I think this is the only same-device solution.

Comment: You don’t want to create a hard-link to a directory. https://askubuntu.com/a/525129

Answer (score 4):

I actually just came across this option that worked perfectly for me:

Actually if you open terminal and...

$ cd /Library/Logs

then sym-link to your new log directory. eg i want my chroot'ed apache logs as 'www'

$ ln -s /chroot/apache/private/var/log www

then re-open Console.app

drill down into /Library/Logs and you will find your sym-linked directory.

;-)

Mohclips.

http://forums.macosxhints.com/showthread.php?t=35680

Comment: Any idea on how to get the log files with columns like the other OS logs?

Answer (score 1):

In Terminal run this command... append any log file directories you want to add

defaults write com.apple.Console LogFolderPaths -array '~/Library/Logs/' '/Library/Logs/' '/var/log/' '/opt/local/var/log/'

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me on Leopard 1.5.7, am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry I thumbed it up before trying. That default doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Since Mavericks, symlink behavior as change so "ln - s" doesn't work anymore.
use [hardlink-osx](https://github.com/selkhateeb/hardlink) instead to create an hardlink to your directory (may be installed via homebrew)

Comment: Although this definitely works, creating a hard-link is usually a bad idea. See https://askubuntu.com/a/525129

Answer (score 1):

Very old post I know but, this is the only way I could get it to work.

```
cd /Library/Logs
sudo mkdir log_files
sudo ln -s /Users/USERNAME/Sites/website/logs/* log_files
```

Answer (score 1):

In mac os 10.11, you may not be able to link to folder of logs, but instead you need to link to each log of logs folder in side console.

```
ln -s /opt/local/apache2/logs/error_log ~/Library/Logs/Apache2/error_log
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just open any text file with console.app and it will add and keep it. Folder's though, no luck on that yet.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to hardlink the files into ~/Library/logs by running:

```
ln /usr/local/var/logs/postgres.log ~/Library/logs
```

Notice the absence of -s.

No luck for directories though.
OSX Sierra 10.12.6

Answer (score -1):

Just tried to do something similar.

I enter this in terminal, while the Console.app was running.

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/var/log/apache2
sudo mv /private/var/log/apache2 /usr/local/var/log/apache2/apache2-old
sudo ln -s /usr/local/var/log/apache2 /private/var/log/apache2
```

Now whenever I open the Console.app it crashes.

Really wish there was a way of adding log files in the files. You CAN do it by dragging and dropping a folder onto the Console.app (given it a directory path as an argument), but the added folder only displays its immediate contents and doesn't allow for recursively descending into folders.

---------EDIT BELOW----------

**Nevermind** I stupidly did something like this leading to infinite recursion in Console.app

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/var/log/apache2
sudo ln -s /private/var/log/apache2/apache2 /usr/local/var/log/apache2
sudo mv /private/var/log/apache2 /usr/local/var/log/apache2/apache2-old
sudo ln -s /usr/local/var/log/apache2 /private/var/log/apache2
```