# Creating directory hard links in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, hardlink

**How can I create a hard link to a directory in Mac OS X?**

This feature has been added to their file system in [Mac OS X v10.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Leopard) (Leopard) (for time machine), but I could not find any information on actually using it from the command line.

Comment: This should be on SuperUser if you're interested in how to access this feature as a user from the commandline. If you'd want to do it programmatically that'd be a different story :-)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Unfortunately Apple has crippled the `ln` command. You can use the following program to create a hard link to a directory:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
 if (argc != 3) {
  fprintf(stderr,"Use: hlink <src_dir> <target_dir>\n");
  return 1;
 }
 int ret = link(argv[1],argv[2]);
 if (ret != 0)
  perror("link");
 return ret;
}
```

Take into account that the hard linked directories may not be in the same parent directory, so you can do this:

```
$ gcc hlink.c -o hlink
$ mkdir child1
$ mkdir parent
$ ./hlink child1 parent/clone2
```

Comment: Hey, I've been using this for a while now - thanks a ton. However, I noticed that if I delete a hard linked directory (rm -rf) it will also wipe the contents of the original source dir.

Makes sense since rm -rf goes through the dir and removes file by file. However, I'd like to have the ability to remove the hardlink directly. Is that possible?

Comment: Have you tried the unlink command and system call?

Comment: +1 (would give more if I could) This has totally saved my bacon!

Comment: Looks like they patched this up... tried this in Snow Leopard and I get "link: Operation not permitted"

Comment: @taber: be sure to create the hard link in a directory different from the source directory's parent (e.g., in parent/ in Freeman's example). This is one of the restrictions outlined in http://osxbook.com/blog/2008/11/09/hfsdebug-40-and-new-hfs-features/

Comment: does anyone know how does timemachine treat hardlinks that exist on a volume being backed up?

Comment: glad I found this.  sorry to resurrect an old thread but this works well for me except for one problem. Finder doesn't want to refresh the content of a directory if I change something in the directory hardlinked to it. Tried on two different macs.    is this normal or is this a Finder bug? 10.11.1. Relaunching Finder forces a refresh btw.

Comment: A word of warning, apfs doesn't support hardlinks and converting your hfs+ to apfs wipes all the multilinked directories (converting them to files of 0 bytes).

Comment: Both "link" and "unlink" calls not working on 10.13.3 (High Sierra) resulting "Operation Not Permitted".

Answer (score 87):

I have bundled up the suggested answer in a Git repository if anybody is interested: https://github.com/selkhateeb/hardlink

Once installed, create a hard link with:

```
hln source destination
```

I also noticed that `unlink` command does not work on Mac OS X v10.6 (Snow Leopard), so I added an option to unlink:

```
hln -u destination
```

---

To install Hardlink, use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and run:

```
brew install hardlink-osx
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me. But you should add Jean-Philippe Pellet comment do README.

Comment: @Sam : I'm on 10.6.8.  Linking is working, but unlinking isn't. :(

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's worth noting that this is now up on [Homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/hardlink-osx.rb). `brew install hardlink-osx`

Comment: Also, it seems the binary is located at hln now, and thus the command to use is hln as opposed to hardlink.

Comment: Works as of today for me for linking!

Comment: I've noticed something interesting with this. This method of linking is quite different than a normal Unix/Linux hardlink-- in terms of removing the original directories. Mac OS X is *not* letting me remove the original directory with the links still in place.

Comment: Hi after a directory is hard linked , is there a way to detect it is a hard link ? I want to do this to conditionally remove the hard links.

Comment: Hmmm... seems on macOS 10.14 I get the error "Operation not permitted" even with `sudo`

Comment: Doesn't work with the new macOS as APFS doesn't allow folder hard links. Workaround is to use `bindfs` utility to  mount the directory. See: https://github.com/selkhateeb/hardlink/issues/31

Comment: brew removed the formula of hardlink-osx

Answer (score 18):

In the answer to the question by the_undefined about how to remove a hardlink to a directory without removing the contents of other directories to which it is linked: As far as I can tell, it can't be done from the command line using builtin commands. However, this little program (inspired by Freeman's post) will do it:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Use: hunlink <dir>\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int ret = unlink(argv[1]);
    if (ret != 0)
        perror("unlink");
    return ret;
}
```

To follow on with Freeman's example,

```
$ gcc hunlink.c -o hunlink
$ echo "foo bar" > child1/baz.txt
$ ./hunlink parent/clone2
```

will remove the hardlink at parent/clone2, but leave the directory `child1` and the file `child1/baz.txt` alone.

Comment: I'm getting `resource busy`. Hardlink was created with binds

Answer (score 13):

Another solution is to use bindfs https://code.google.com/p/bindfs/ which is installable via port:

```
sudo port install bindfs
sudo bindfs ~/source_dir ~/target_dir
```

Comment: this works for me on Mojave v10.14.3

Comment: doesn't work for me on Catalina: mkdir aa; mkdir bb; bindfs aa bb will return an error (Failed to resolve mount point `bb': No such file or directory
), I added a github issue: https://github.com/mpartel/bindfs/issues/83

Comment: It works flawlessly on Catalina now.
(Issue Thomas mentioned is fixed)